# Count rows matching 'x' in column A OR column B, while ALSO matching 'y' in column C

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

Sample Data:

```
   A      B     C
1 Jene   Alex
2 Sasha  Jene   X
3 Alex   Sasha  X
4 Alex   Jene  
5 Alex   Sasha  X
```

I  want my count to include all rows that have the name in either column A or column B while also having a 'X' in column C.

So, I'd like to have the following result:

```
Jene = 1      //  (B2 & C2)
Alex = 2      //  (A3 & C3, A5 & C5)
Sasha = 3     //  (A2 & C2, B3 & C3, B5 & C5)
```

This is because in any row in the range A1:B5 I counted the occurences of each name only if there was an X in its row.

I tried

```
=COUNTIFS(A$1:B$5, "Jene", C$1:C$5, "<>")
```

But I get an error which says that the arguments differ in size.

Comment: do two countifs and sum them

Comment: Like that?
=COUNTIF(A$1:B$5, "Jene") - COUNTIF(C$1:C$5, "X") ?
Becuase this one doesn't work well... It gives 0

Comment: no: `=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"Jene",C1:C5, "X")+COUNTIFS(B1:B5,"Jene",C1:C5, "X")`

Comment: Thats nice! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use SUMPRODUCT to count all instances where there is an "X" in Column C, and the specified name in Column A **OR** Column B.  In the formula below, the '*****' works like an '**AND**' and the '**+**' works like an '**OR**'.

```
 Alex  =  SUMPRODUCT((C1:C5="X")*((A1:A5=E1)+(B1:B5=E1)))
 Jene  =  SUMPRODUCT((C1:C5="X")*((A1:A5=E2)+(B1:B5=E2)))
 Sasha =  SUMPRODUCT((C1:C5="X")*((A1:A5=E3)+(B1:B5=E3)))

     A     B     C     D     E     F
1  Jene   Alex             Alex    2
2  Sasha  Jene   X         Jene    1
3  Alex   Sasha  X         Sasha   3
4  Alex   Jene      
5  Alex   Sasha  X
```